# Derived class interpreted as base class when object returned by controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an Action method that returns an object derived from the class 'List':

```
class Derived<T> : List<T>
{
    public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpGet]
public Derived<string> MyActionMethod()
{
    var results = new Derived<string> { AdditionalProperty = 123 };
    results.Add("ABCD");
    results.Add("EFGH");
    return results;
}
```

When I call the action method (I use swagger to test), I have only the `List` returned, not the `Derived` class. Here is the result:

```
[
    "ABCD",
    "EFGH"
]
```

The desired result would have the `AdditionalProperty` included in the serialization.

I really would like to understand why is that happening. And How can I make the action method return the `Derived` class?

Comment: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt) Composition instead of inheritance will also fix this issue

Comment: @mjwills Postman gives exactly the same results as swagger.

Comment: My guess is the JSON parser uses reflection and asks "Does it inherit from IEnumerable<T>". And if it does then it will be serialized into an array.

Comment: I ended up using composition over inheritance. Thank you.